# Сертификаты Microsoft

Tags: .net, сертификат

Решил сдать сертификационный экзамен. Не могли бы обладатели сертификатов подробнее рассказать о процедуре сертификации (обучение, учебники, стоимость, экзамен и т.д)
Интересуют сертификаты MCTS, MCPD, MCAD (.net 4.0 Web/Win development)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сертифицировался на MCPD Windows Developer 4. В общем, обучиться можно самому. Вот [отсюда](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/mcpd.aspx#tab2) берешь необходимые номера к экзаменам и ищешь учебные пособия по ним, готовишься. Приходишь в экзаменационный центр Prometric в своем городе. Выясняешь стоимость и процедуру сдачи экзаменов (цена за экзамен ~$50). Регистрируешься и сдаешь по одному. На разные экзамены дают разное количество времени, в среднем 1:20 - 1:30. Количество вопросов в одном экзамене около 40. Я не знаю, как сейчас, но когда я сдавал многих учебных пособий еще не было. Средняя цена на одно учебное пособие $40-50.

**UPD**

Вот центры Prometric в РБ. Звони, узнавай, регистрируйся на [сайте Prometric](http://prometric.com) и удачи. Должен огорчить, 70-711 стоит $80, остальные, наверное, столько же.

[image]

Comment: Т.е. как я понял для получения сертификата необходимо сдать около четырех экзаменов? Что будет, если я не сдам какой нибудь?

Comment: Вроде есть вторая попытка. Это надо уточнить, в любом случае перед тем как тратить на что-либо из этого нужно сходить в Prometric центр и узнать все из первых уст. С другой стороны - хорошо подготовишься, сдашь без проблем.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я живу в Белоруссии и у нас нет представительства Microsoft